Automatic range switching control in the low-pass filter from the transceiver USDX
I want to automate the switching of the low-pass filter (enter link description here, here is its circuit: ) on the power amplifier for the USDX transceiver (enter link description here). Bistable relays in USDX are controlled via the i2c bus.
Please, help me implement a control circuit for conventional relays in my low-pass filter using signals from this bus.
Thanks,
